# How does the definition for `apply-partially` work in Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, closures, elisp

The Emacs code for `apply-partially` is this:

```
(defun apply-partially (fun &rest args)
  "Return a function that is a partial application of FUN to ARGS.
ARGS is a list of the first N arguments to pass to FUN.
The result is a new function which does the same as FUN, except that
the first N arguments are fixed at the values with which this function
was called."
  `(closure (t) (&rest args)
            (apply ',fun ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg) `',arg) args) args)))
```

It returns a list that looks a lot like a lambda expression, except that `lambda` is replaced by `closure (t)`. For example, `(apply-partially 'cons 1)` returns this:

```
(closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote cons) (quote 1) args))
```

which, as far as I can tell, looks and works exactly like this:

```
(lambda (&rest args) (apply (quote cons) (quote 1) args))
```

except that the "closure" expression does not have the "self-quoting" property of a lambda, so when I try to evaluate it, Emacs informs me that `closure` has no function definition: `Lisp error: (void-function closure)`.

I can't find any references in the Elisp manual to using the symbol `closure` in this way. It seems like some kind of internal Emacs magic. The closure expression is clearly not being evaluated according to the normal rules (since doing that manually gives an error).

So what's going on here? Do I need to grep the C code for references to "closure" to find out?

EDIT: It appears that in Emacs 23 and below, `apply-partially` simply uses the `lexical-let` from the cl package to make a closure. The definition above is from version "24.0.90.1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in `eval.c`, in the `funcall_lambda` function:

```
  if (EQ (XCAR (fun), Qclosure))
{
  fun = XCDR (fun); /* Drop `closure'.  */
  lexenv = XCAR (fun);
  CHECK_LIST_CONS (fun, fun);
}
  else
lexenv = Qnil;
```

`closure (t)` appears to be the lexical equivalent of `lambda`. The second element, `(t)`, gets assigned to `lexenv`, so I guess this element is for closing over lexical values defined outside of the function itself or something.

I suspect that the lack of self-quoting may be an oversight, which can be remedied as follows:

```
(defmacro make-self-quoting (name)
  "Make NAME into a self-quoting function like `lambda'."
  `(defmacro ,name (&rest cdr)
     (list 'function (cons ',name cdr))))
(make-self-quoting closure)
```

Comment: Right, in the case of apply-partially, the lexical environment is empty, but there is still one difference: the `args` argument will be lexically bound, whereas with a `lambda` it would be dynamically bound.  This ensures that the name `args` will not interfere with other uses of that variable elsewhere.

Comment: As for the lack of self-quoting, it's not really an oversight, it's simply not needed: `(closure ...)` should never occur in source code.

Answer (score 1):

With my "GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i686-pc-cygwin)" it is defined as

```
(defun apply-partially (fun &rest args)
  "Return a function that is a partial application of FUN to ARGS.              
ARGS is a list of the first N arguments to pass to FUN.                         
The result is a new function which does the same as FUN, except that            
the first N arguments are fixed at the values with which this function          
was called."
  (lexical-let ((fun fun) (args1 args))
    (lambda (&rest args2) (apply fun (append args1 args2)))))
```

Understanding how it works seems to be quite easy here: The `lambda` remembers the partial set of args and appends the rest when calling the original function.

Comment: I'm running Emacs 24, which now has its own lexical scoping that doesn't rely on the cl package. I guess the `closure` thing is new to Emacs 24.

Comment: If it `closure` is a symbol then apropos must have something about it?

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/closure2.el has a `defmacro closure` but it is not clear if it is part of Emacs.

Comment: No, the symbol "closure" is not mentioned anywhere in the docs. It is never used directly from any elisp code, only from C code, so it is in some sense a part of Emacs' internals.